# Disabling to show console for my Application not Working (F12 is ok but can't able to disable CLT+SHFT+I)

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

For one of my project I do not want to use the user to see the console or resources using F12 , also for the application is an internal confidential so that I will maanger a policy in chrome, not to see the Developer tools in Menu .

When I try to use CLT+STFT+I I find its not working. Putting my current code

```
document.onkeypress = function(event) {
  event = (event || window.event);
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 16 && event.keyCode == 73) {
    return false;
  }
};
document.onmousedown = function(event) {
  event = (event || window.event);
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 16 && event.keyCode == 73) {
    return false;
  }
};
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  event = (event || window.event);
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 16 && event.keyCode == 73) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: You can't do that.  If you don't want users to see resources, don't send them in the first place.  Once data hits the user's machine, you can no longer control it.

Comment: if you app disables stuff in my browser, your app is going in the garbage and you as a developer/provider will be blacklisted. do **NOT** mess with the user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful because all operating system don't have the same behavior. And if the person is good, he will also access to a developer toolbar. Why do you want to block this browser feature ? Do you block right click -> inspect element too ? :)